# How to change the value of a variable in another class in Angular

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have two classes A and B

Class A

```
export class A{
   static id: number = 0;

   constructor() {
      A.id = A.id;
   }
}
```

Class B

```
import{A} from '../A';
export class B {
   constructor() {}
   changeId(id:number){
     A.id = id;
   }
}
```

My problem is this, i want to change the value of `id` in Class A when the `changeId()` function in Class B is triggered. I don't want the value to remain 0 because I want to use `id` in other parts of my application and the value needs to be dynamic. Please how can this be possible ?

**NB** I'm using this for an Ionic 3 app

Comment: Not related to `angularjs`, untagged!

Comment: Your current code changes the value of id in A since it is static.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import { Events } from 'ionic-angular';

export class A{
   static id: number = 0;

   constructor(public events: Events) {
      events.subscribe("idChange", (id) => {
         A.id = id; //id is a static variable 
      }); 
   }
}


import { Events } from 'ionic-angular';

export class B {
   constructor(public events: Events) {}
   changeId(id:number){
      this.events.publish("idChange", id);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your current code already changes the value of id in A since it is static.

```
let b = new B();
b.changeId(3);
console.log(A.id); //prints 3
b.changeId(6);
console.log(A.id); //prints 6
```

Comment: Yea the value changes but if i try to access the value in another class let me say  Class C the value will still remain the same. I think what i did in Class B will only create an instance of Class A that why it doesn't change the actual value of Class A